# How to recover .java files in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

My Netbeans Java project is not showing `.java` files. Instead there are compiled `.class` files in the build directory. I can still edit the code though. I need to get the `.java` files back there somehow. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reach the Netbeans folder manually and see whether the files are there. It's normally called NetBeansProjects and it should be in your home directory. Then find your project and look for src folder inside there.

If the files are lost, you could decompile the class files as Saket said, but it should be your last resource! Do you have a backup, don't you? **Your source code should be treated like gold**, is the product of your work. Losing it could mean lose days or months of work.

Normally I use Git for version control, push at least daily to a remote repository on one server, and backup my whole home folder daily to a different server with a script.

In turn the disks on the servers (Git and backup) are also backed up weekly with two weeks of backlog. Yes, I'm spending more to have this kind of multiple backups, but I had my share of bad experiences in my youth, and hopefully learnt from them.

Answer (score 11):

I know this post is old but it is one of the first that shows up on google so I felt I should post this information for future seekers:

In NetBeans there is a History of All Objects used in a project that can be restored:

- Right click on the folder/directory that the files had been deleted
- Choose Local History – Restore Deleted
- Select the File(s) you want to Restore
- Done

I hope this solution helps...

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE may be using the already compiled `.class` files lying in the output directory of the project. And what you may be opening up is the .class itself (in a IDE-decompiled version)

You can get them back (from those .class files) using a decompiler (if that's allowed) - for example, **[cavaj](http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic find the directory your project is in and search for .java files.  I don't know NetBeans but all the IDEs are similar.  It's common for them to bug out but your file should still be there.

I recommend starting a fresh project with your files.

Answer (score -1):

In netbeans they should be in the Src folder of your netbeans project